# Detecting Missing Objects

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, artificial-intelligence

I want to detect missing objects of an image. Here is the situation

1. You have an image of a room. There is a ball in the room.
2. You have another image of the same room (Light conditions similar). The only difference is, the ball is missing.
3. Now I need to opencv to compare these 2 images and find what is missing.

I know the first step of doing this, and that is calculating the histogram of both the images and comparing them . If something is missing from the second image, then the histogram values will differ.

Now, how to detect that "ball" is missing? Using template matching?

Comment: Are both of the pictures from the same angle?

Comment: Then just subtract one image from another and use blob detection.

Comment: @Blender: wow, any link for a recommended article please?

Comment: @Blender:mm,I dnt know blob case. I need to learn it first.mmmmmm. Can I draw a rectangler over the missing thing?

Comment: You can get the bounding box of the missing blob, so sure.

Comment: @Blender: cool. Please provide the link as an answer

Comment: Please provide your images, different cases may need different technologies.

Comment: is it always the same ball? can you provide images?

Comment: @samkhan13: No, ball is an example

Comment: @cxyzs7: Ball is an example. It might be a ball, table, or whatever. OK, in real case, this will happen via camera. Whatever the thing which was there before 5 seconds, but not now need to be identified.

Comment: @Blender: Refering to my last 2 comments, is your method still possible? I think yes, but I need recommendation. Please help

Comment: @Blender: Ca you please provide your idea?

Comment: @Knight: Do your own research. Google doesn't bite.

Comment: @Blender: I will take it as NO then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in comments, you can easily subtract those 2 images. IIRC Mat has overloaded - [minus] operator. So `sub = img1 - img2;` should be enough as long as imgs are `cv::Mat` objects.

About the blobs take a look at following tutorials at OpenCV website:

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/hull/hull.html

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rects_circles/bounding_rects_circles.html

Comment: I cant see this as being very predictable?

Comment: Ball is an example. It might be a ball, table, or whatever. OK, in real case, this will happen via camera. Whatever the thing which was there before 5 seconds, but not now need to be identified. is tis still possible? Every 5 seconds, a picture will be taken from te camera anyway, so video analyzing not needed

Comment: It depends. Using my proposed method, you will be notified, that the scene has changed. But you don't get info what is the object missing. OpenCV has no clue, that the bright blob in image is ball or table or anything. You will have to add this functionality in other way.

Comment: Fine. Thank you for the help. I really appreciate it :)